Coerce dataframe dtypes so dask doesn't issue a warning?
I have a normal pandas.DataFrame which contains some string columns.
symbol_exch = pd.DataFrame(
    [
        {'exchange': s['exchange'], 'symbol': s['symbol']}
        for s in exchange.symbols
    ],
)

I would like to merge this with a dask.dataframe which is constructed from an apache.arrow dataset, and so has arrow datatypes rather than the pandas-native equivalent.
As such, I am converting the dtypes to string[pyarrow]
symbol_exch = symbol_exch.astype(
    dtype={'exchange': 'string[pyarrow]', 'symbol': 'string[pyarrow]'},
)

As can be seen, this seemingly works correctly, the dtypes are reported as string[pyarrow]:
>>> symbol_exch.dtypes
exchange    string[pyarrow]
symbol      string[pyarrow]
dtype: object

So now I attempt to merge my dask.dataframe with the above:
df = dask.dataframe.from_delayed(tasks, meta)
df = df.merge(symbol_exch, on='symbol', how='left')

The operation does actually complete successfully, but dask issues a warning:
/usr/local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/dask/dataframe/multi.py:520: UserWarning: Merging dataframes with merge column data type mismatches: 
+----------------------+-----------------+-------------+
| Merge columns        | left dtype      | right dtype |
+----------------------+-----------------+-------------+
| ('symbol', 'symbol') | string[pyarrow] | string      |
+----------------------+-----------------+-------------+
Cast dtypes explicitly to avoid unexpected results.
  warnings.warn(

Even though I explicitly set the dtypes in the right-hand dataframe, the warning is still issued.
What do I need to do to my symbol_exch dataframe in order to suppress this warning?

After digging deep into the internals of dask and pandas, I eventually found is_dtype_equal in pandas.core.dtypes.common.
Ultimately, both dtypes are checked and found to be of type ExtensionDtype.
When printing the dtype object of both sides, they print the same thing:
>>> dtype(target)
string[pyarrow]

>>> dtype(source)
string[pyarrow]

I found that ExtensionDtype.__str__ just returns the ExtensionDtype.name member:
    def __str__(self) -> str:
        return self.name

However, when comparing for equality, ExtensionDtype.__eq__ goes on to check the contents of ExtensionDtype._metadata
    def __eq__(self, other: object) -> bool:
        """
        Check whether 'other' is equal to self.

        By default, 'other' is considered equal if either

        * it's a string matching 'self.name'.
        * it's an instance of this type and all of the attributes
          in ``self._metadata`` are equal between `self` and `other`.

        Parameters
        ----------
        other : Any

        Returns
        -------
        bool
        """
        if isinstance(other, str):
            try:
                other = self.construct_from_string(other)
            except TypeError:
                return False
        if isinstance(other, type(self)):
            return all(
                getattr(self, attr) == getattr(other, attr) for attr in self._metadata
            )
        return False

When printing the dtype._metadata object of both sides, I find they are different:
>>> target._metadata
('storage', 'pyarrow_dtype')

>>> source._metadata
('storage',)

So finally it can be seen that even though one can specify df.astype, this doesn't actually convert 100% to the correct `dtype.
In fact, the underlying type of each ExtensionDtype was different:
>>> type(target)
pandas.core.dtypes.dtypes.ArrowDtype

>>> type(source)
pandas.core.arrays.string_.StringDtype

This led me to realise that I need to construct my source dataframe with dtype=pandas.core.dtypes.dtypes.ArrowDtype 
symbol_exch = pd.DataFrame(
    [
        {'exchange': s['exchange'], 'symbol': s['symbol']}
        for s in exchange.symbols
    ],
    dtype=pandas.core.dtypes.dtypes.ArrowDtype(pyarrow.string())
)

Now the dtypes match, and the warning goes away.
